# change cell's backGroundColor from imagePickerController

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

Tell me pls how to change cell's `backGroundColor` from  imagePickerController func:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        //let imageUser = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.editedImage] as! UIImage

        let indexPath = IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellRegisterMarket", for: indexPath) as! cellRegisterMarket
        cell.backgroundColor = .red
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace this

```
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellRegisterMarket", for: indexPath) as! cellRegisterMarket
```

with

```
let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at:indexPath) as! cellRegisterMarket
```

BTW this isn't a good way , update the model and reload the collection

Comment: I think Reloading is more costly we may update the model and also cell with beginUpdate method specially when you have a long lasting tableView data, what you say about this?

Comment: @AbuUlHassan he should reload that specific indexPath only

Answer (score 2):

You should try this :

```
let indexPath = IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)
let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! cellRegisterMarket
cell.backgroundColor = .red
```